# NULL vs NOT NULL Performance differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, null

Recently i was looking at a SQL table we have and noticed the following.

```
    [FooColumn] CHAR (1) DEFAULT ('N') NOT NULL,
```

Above you can see that FooColumn Would always default to 'N' but still has a "NOT NULL" specified.

Would there be some Storage/Performance differences in setting a column to "NOT NULL" instead of "NULL" ?

How would SQL Server Treat a "NOT NULL: different from a "NULL" column ?

**NOTE: This is ONLY for SQL and not the overhead of externally doing NULL checks**

Comment: NULL or NOT NULL should be there for a reason. Don't bother about performance or storage differences.

Comment: Why not bother about performance or storage ?
Every bit makes a difference.

Comment: A wrongly designed database is so much worse than a bit or nano-second spent.

Comment: The db designer probably didn't want anyone to do this: `INSERT INTO Table (foo) VALUES (null);`.  Nulls can be a real pain to work with.  The inventor of the null reference called them a [billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare).

Comment: @destination-data - SQL `NULL`s only share a *name* with null references. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point!  I feel a bit silly now.

Comment: You have some good responses but you are asking the wrong question and the wrong audience. No one can really answer your question without understanding how this column is used and the assumptions that are already coded into any applications/process that use this table. A default constraint does not substitute for disallowing null values in a column. You cannot address "performance" until you **know** that nothing depends on the possibility of a null value. NB Change always involves risk - are you willing to take it?

Comment: The designer may have thought to overcome the result of in INSERT IGNORE or a multi line insert of nulls to a not null field - in fact 0 is written to an int field ' ' to a string field etc). From my (limited) tests you cannot override this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only use NOT NULL when you have a reason (ie required field for UI or for backend relationships). NOT NULL vs NULL performance is negligible and as per [this article from 2016 (SQL SERVER)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/NULL/116167/), performance shouldn't be a consideration when deciding NOT NULL vs NULL.

Even though that field will default to 'N', a command could still set it to NULL if nulls were allowed. It comes down to is NULL a valid piece of data for that column.

**EDIT**

In a data-driven technical application, in my experience these are some guidelines we use:

- for numeric fields, NULL is unknown to the user, and all numbers have meaning.
- for string fields, NULL and "" are identical to the user, so it depends on you backend application.
- I know that your question was excluding ISNULL checks but if you are doing a lot of them then it might be a code smell that those fields should be NOT NULL if possible since they can get expensive.

Comment: I agree with "It comes down to is NULL a valid piece of data for that column.", however i have found very few instances where this is true if you have a data structure describing something it should be fully populated, even if you use the value 'Unknown' instead of null

Comment: We have numeric fields that negative, 0, or positive numbers are valid technical pieces of data. While the data is not required on initial save, it may be entered later. In this business case, it is valid since the data is unknown until they enter it and there is no substitute that is valid.

Comment: @RegBes, I would love if the data was fully populated, unfortunately, that isn't always realistic when it comes to data from users. Also, foreign keys if the relationship may or may not exist.

Answer (score 4):

It's a complicated "debate".

NULL means unknown. It's different from 0 or empty string.

NOT NULL means you NEED to insert a value in there, always, even if it's a blank string or a 0. Many designers argue that's it's better design. Other see no issues with having NULL values. Different software houses will enforce different rules.

Having a "default" value simply means that when you create new records without specifying a value, it will use the default value instead. This is regardless of whether the field is NULL or NOT NULL.

Having NULL values MAY have an impact on performance (as the DBMS needs to deal with this special case), it will depend on which DBMS you are using, which version, which config etc... You need to do bench-marking with your own setup to see what's what.

Here's a good article: http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/designing-performance-null-or-not-null

Answer (score 0):

As the question is asked :

> "NULL vs NOT NULL Performance differences"

, the answer must be based on the storage structure of the line and the difference in treatment of the line in the event of a Null.

The answer is: there is no difference.

Here are articles discussing line structure into SQL server:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/
https://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/10/15/sql-server-storage-engine-data-pages-and-data-rows/

Here the column is defined as CHAR(1) so it is a fixed size column. 
The difference between an empty string''' and Null is checked in the line structure information. There is no structural space saving storing null or an empty string; the structural information does not change depending on the definition of the constraint.

If you are looking for performance in the relation of data structure then you need to look elsewhere.

IMHO :
A column defined as `CHAR(1)` often contains coded information with few distinct values. 
It is also common that this kind of column points to a "translation" table through FK.
So, if it is a "2-state indicator value" then the BIT type can be used knowing that all columns of this type are grouped together in the same byte.
If more different cases (more distinct values) are needed then the tinyint type will also occupy 1 byte of fixed size but will not require validation of the collation to process ties. (note : TinyInt offer more values than `CHAR(1)` )

Elsewhere, if you don't have a FK constraint yet, this must be balanced.

Answer (score -1):

```
 [FooColumn] CHAR (1) DEFAULT ('N') NOT NULL,
```

It is far better than NCHAR(1), VARCHAR(1) or NVARCHAR(1) ! 
(For MySQL check FooColumn CHARACTER SET)

But, depend your RDBMs and existant development, investigate if you can use BIT or TinyInt (no collation)

The extra cost of the needed test to check 'NOT NULL' compared to none for 'NULL' is very, very minimal.